# How to open files and sub-folders in the same window in emacs?

Tags: emacs, window, dired

I would like to open files/sub-folders in the same window which is already established in my emacs(I understand the difference between Emacs frames and windows).

Currently when I jump into Emacs I typically use `C-x f` in order to navigate to the folder I will be working inside of; once there I can look at the folder and its contents in Dired nicely.

However, when I then try and open a file or a sub-folder within this, by clicking or selecting it through navigating with my keyboard, it then spawns a new window beside my current one, making my screen extremely cluttered when I only wanted one window open.

How canI tell Emacs that when I am navigating in Dired I want new files and folders I move into to be opened in the window I am already working in so that I do not have to keep closing and re-opening random windows?

Apologies if this is a newbie question I am a fairly new emacs user and couldn't find this question posed elsewhere.

Comment: Did you mean `C-x d`, right?

Comment: For a starting point, take a look at the [Online Docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-Visiting.html) or read the same docs in Emacs with `C-h i m <Emacs> RET g <Dired>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "dired"
  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<mouse-2>") #'dired-mouse-find-file)
  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<RET>") #'dired-find-file))
```

It behaved normally for me when I pressed `<RET>`, but the mouse click indeed opened another window. I used `C-h k` to see what the commands were named.

Comment: Tried adding this to my .emacs and restarted emacs. It gave me this error:

`Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/cthulhu/.emacs’:`

`Symbol's value as variable is void: dired-mode-map`

I tried using the commands but the windows still seem to pop up around the original window. It looks like it isn't recognizing the variable dired-mode-map thus it is void.

Comment: Which Emacs version are you using? Is it a vanilla setup? Try using/testing emacs without customizations, by launching it with the `-Q` option: `$ emacs -Q`. When in  `Dired` buffer, hit `C-h m` and see the defined bindings for this mode.

Comment: @AntonHibl I've updated the code to fix that bug.